# Python dict entries not being referenced properly

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I'm trying to create new objects on screen with new data this way:

```
spawnedObjectDict = dict()
while True: # main loop
if mouseClicked == True:
        RectangleName = "Rectangle" + str((len(spawnedObjectDict)))
        spawnedObjectDict[RectangleName] = SpawnedRectangle
        spawnedObjectDict[RectangleName].positionX = mouseX
        spawnedObjectDict[RectangleName].positionY = mouseY
```

This SHOULD be creating new objects and assigning them coordinates equal to the mouse. However, it keeps assigning ALL of them new mouse coordinates, so they simply stack on top of each other. At first I assumed it was only drawing one, or only one object was in the dict for some reason, but I added this to make sure:

```
def drawRectCoords(RectName, theDict, x, y, size_x, size_y):
    for i in iter(theDict):
        BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
        textSurf = BASICFONT.render(str(theDict['Rectangle0'].positionX) + ", " + \
                                    str(theDict['Rectangle0'].positionY), True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0))
        textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
        textRect.topleft = (x, y)


        textSurf2 = BASICFONT.render(str(len(theDict)) + ", " + RectName, True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0))
        textRect2 = textSurf2.get_rect()
        textRect2.topleft = (150, (20*len(theDict)))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf2, textRect2)
```

Sure enough, the coordinates of Rectangle0 are changing each time, but textSurf2 updates each time to show that RectangleName is changing and the length of spawnedObjectDict is increasing.

Comment: Why are you using a dict instead of a list anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new instance of `SpawnedRectangle`, do this:

```
spawnedObjectDict[RectangleName] = SpawnedRectangle()
```

What you are currently doing assigns the class `SpawnedRectangle` to different keys in the dictionary.